# Text field text drawn at bottom instead of centre

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uitextfield

I'm working on an iPhone app and I've a problem: the text in my text field is drawn at the bottom. Can any one help me to display it centered?

Comment: Can you check its vertical alignment in the xib file? Keep the vertical alignment at the center.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following instruction:

```
textField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
```